# How to edit user attributes in AWS Cognito User Pool for specific user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito User Pool and have created some users. Now I would like to change some of the attributes for a specific user such as name, address, etc...

Is it possible to do this on an AWS Website? If so, how?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The console does not have that capability but it can be done in the AWS Command Line Interface.

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes \
    --user-pool-id xxx \
    --username yyy \
    --user-attributes Name=xxx,Value=yyy Name=ttt,Value=sss ...
```

Custom attributes use the following syntax:

```
--user-attributes Name="custom:attributeName",Value="value with space"
```

You need to set up your credentials with cli first (only the first time), via the command:

```
aws configure
```

but after that it is straightforward. For more:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes help
```

Comment: does aws cli clash/conflicts will amplify cli ?

Answer (score 15):

The new Cognito console interface is able to edit now.

From console go to Amazon Cognito > User pools > {the user pool you want to select} > {user you want to edit}

Under "User attributes" card, click "Edit" on the right
[image]

Comment: I don't have this "User attributes" card, do you have any idea why please?

Comment: @Wenneguen did you try to click into the respective user pool? Also did you opt in for the new UI (usually some toggle button at one of the top corners) by any chance?

Comment: It's in the new UI of aws

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked how to change user attributes in Cognito.  While the primary User Attributes and the custom attributes, can he viewed in the console, they cannot be changed there.
Here is a link to the Python API to access User properties: [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.add_custom_attributes).  The `update_user_attributes()` method may be what you are looking for.

A broader set of APIs for cognito can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html).